# rails convert multiple columns query to strftime("%H" ) ... NoMethodError: undefined method `strftime'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, strftime

I am trying to convert all the times from `08:00:00 UTC to 8:00`
by using strftime

Here is the Profile model with fields.

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :sun, :mon, :wed, :tue, :thu, :fri, :sat
end
```

Here is the query.

```
Profile.select('mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun').where('usermodel_id = ?', 3).strftime('%H:%M')
```

Error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `strftime'
```

Will you please help me convert the format: just like this 
Sun: 9:00, Mon: 9:00 etc

I really need some help, please

Answer (score 2):

You're running the `strftime` method against an active record collection, but the method is to be run against Ruby `Time` objects. You have to iterate on the collection, extract the times and then you can call `strftime` on them.

For example:

```
profile_collection = Profile.select('mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun').where('usermodel_id = ?', 3)

time_strings = profile_collection.map do |profile|
  %w(mon tue wed thu fri sat sun).map do |field|
    profile.send(field)
  end.map { |field| field.strftime('%H:%M') if field }.compact
end
```

What it does: extracts all of the time fields, then applies strftime method on each; returned array will contain an array for each profile, which in turn contains the time string for each day.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the reply, i have sun and sun nil for profiles who are not available on those days and therefore i am gettig undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass.

Comment: Updated my answer to account for that, `compact` just removes `nil` values that will happen when the `if` condition is not met.

Comment: Oh God..You are great.. May you never see a grief in your life ;)

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if you're satisfied with it? Thanks!